# function callback using std::bind in ros 2 subscription

Tags: ros, ros2, rclcpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Using std::bind with rclcpp::Node::create_subscription() throws compilation errors.

For example, I cannot use

```
sub_input_ = node->create_subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::Imu>("input",
  std::bind(
      &input_surface_indices_callback,
      this, <argument1>,<argument2>));
```

However using lamdas as a callback function is ok in this case.
Any help/information on this is welcome.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289207/function-callback-using-std::bind-in-ros-2-subscription/) by [Skyking](https://answers.ros.org/users/31939/skyking/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2018-04-20

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-20**:
What about showing us such a "compilation error"? We cannot help you without you showing us what happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe this is the same issue as reported in here:
https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/issues/273

`std::bind` with additional arguments is not getting resolved correctly. However, I believe if you extract your `std::bind` to a `std::function` and then pass the function instance to the callback it will work.

```
std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::msg::Imu>)> fnc = std::bind(
   &input_surface_indices_callback, this, std::placeholders::_1, <argument1>, <argument2>);
sub_input_ = node->create_subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::Imu>("input", fnc);
```

I am assuming here that your callback has a signature like:

```
void input_surface_indices_callback(std::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::msg::Imu>, Argument1T arg1, Argument2T arg2);
```

Could you try that out and see if it works for you?

---

Originally posted by [Karsten](https://answers.ros.org/users/8211/karsten/) with karma: 643 on 2018-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-11-01**:
I was able to pass extra parameters to the callbacks
in bouncy using the std::function method https://github.com/lucasw/v4l2ucp/blob/5fd86d65d5862684c651fa191081ff7e8c9dac2b/v4l2ucp/src/mainWindow.cpp#L152 (though I'm probably going replace the subscribers with service/s later)

**Comment by [merosss](https://answers.ros.org/users/14411/merosss/) on 2022-12-29**:
It's a pity that this function broke in ros2. This gave me headaches for days, thanks a lot for your solution, worked as a charm!